# how to create a unique slug using Postgres and TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to create a unique slug and save to database. But I am not getting a logic here. I am trying to clear it-

suppose I receive a `title` field from frontend-

`{title: this is the blog title}`

For this title slug will be `this-is-the-blog-title`

Here, If title will be same every time, then I need to create slug like this for newer document-

```
this-is-the-blog-title-1
this-is-the-blog-title-2
this-is-the-blog-title-3
this-is-the-blog-title-4
this-is-the-blog-title-5
this-is-the-blog-title-6
this-is-the-blog-title-7
this-is-the-blog-title-8
this-is-the-blog-title-9
........................
```

But I am not getting any idea how can I do that.

Here is my try-

```
const slugTitle = slugify(this.title)
//this-is-blog-title
const exist = await this.model.findOne({slug: slugTitle})
if(!exist) {
    await this.model.create({slug: slugTitle})
} else {
    await this.model.create({slug: slugTitle + ""}) //Here what I do, I am not getting any idea
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i usually play around with date, it's simple and easy. I think it's a plus when you make it to tell when the blog was posted. Like this:

```
const date = new Date()
const slugTitle = slugify(this.title)

const slug = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()}-${slugTitle}`
// 2023-1-30-this-is-the-blog-title
```

You can shape it as how you want.

If you concern the uniqueness, concat random string smth like `date.getTime()`.
It would be `// 2023-1-30-this-is-the-blog-title-1675061789689`